# Redirecting specific IP and Port to a Docker container on Windows: need guidance

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, proxy, docker

Goal is to provide more than one VPN connection from one computer and redirect traffic. I'm currently trying to do this via Docker desktop.

I created a dockerfile.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y && apt install openfortivpn -y && apt-get install ppp -y && apt install net-tools -y && apt install iputils-ping -y && apt install iproute2 -y && apt install iptables -y

USER root
```

I run the container with the following command

```
docker run --privileged --net=host -it forticlient-image
```

I provide a VPN connection in the container with the following command.

```
openfortivpn 80.155.9.160:443 -u test -p test
```

Network routings in the container are as follows.

> [route -n](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRssW.png)

ipconfig on my Windows pc

> [ipconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr9jb.png)

Let's get to the main issue. I want to redirect TCP traffic from the IP address '192.168.2.111' on Windows to the Docker container using the following command. This IP address is a remote server that I can access via VPN.

I tried to direct the 192.168.2.111 traffic on Windows to the Docker container with the following command.

```
route add 192.168.2.111 mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.1.5
```

As you can see below, I am unable to establish a redirection from Windows.

> [telnet in container (success)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gy9sL.png)

> [telnet in windows (fail)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXltR.png)

I'm not good at networking. If you would like to help me, I would appreciate a little more explanation.

**Note:** If there is anything wrong with this post, please send a comment.